# Static Header not working: themeforest website template

Tags: html, css, menu, static, header

I purchased a website HTML5 template from here: http://themeforest.net/item/porto-responsive-html5-template/full_screen_preview/4106987

However after uploading logo.png, the static header isn't working. You can see form the demo site [here](http://themeforest.net/item/porto-responsive-html5-template/full_screen_preview/4106987) that when you scroll, the header stays. However it seems to have glitched on my site (marketbot.net). It simply isn't responding! What code do I have to add/ replace/ remove? All I did was upload logo.png and the header is not working.

Comment: Why don't you contact [Crivos](http://themeforest.net/user/Crivos)?

Comment: This is a programming forum. This question doesn't belong here. Contact the people who sold you the template.

Comment: You cannot expect us to purchase a $14 template just to fix a bug that a user with 1 rep has had. That's not how SO works. Contact the author and if you continue to have issues contact ThemeForest support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See the theme forum**

http://www.crivos.com/forums/

Navbar fixed

http://www.crivos.com/forums/topic/navbar-fixed/

Change home logo

http://www.crivos.com/forums/topic/changing-logo-on-home-page/